# Restcomm jDiameter: Event Charging Client

Tags: restcomm, diameter-protocol

I'm new to Mobicents/Restcomm. We need to setup a basic DCCA client application which will receive REST request from clients and send CCR (Event Charging without reservation) to Billing server.

Where can I find some detailed instructions (preferably step by step guide) to start, install, configure, develop/customize and test?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Arif

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the documentation at http://documentation.telestax.com/core/diameter/Diameter_User_Guide.html and some of the examples in the project itself https://github.com/RestComm/jdiameter/tree/master/examples ?

You can also look at examples from SIP Servlets using jDiameter https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/tree/master/sip-servlets-examples/diameter-event-charging